# Chef Ruby - Get names of a directory and store it in an array?

Tags: ruby, get, chef-infra, names, cookbook

I have this code in Ruby, and it works, but I want to implement it in Chef Ruby:

```
array = Array.new
accepted_formats = [".txt"]
Dir.foreach("/../dir") do |file|
        accepted_formats.include? File.extname(file)
        array << file
end
```

Because the Ruby code would be execute after the Chef code, so I won't.

I tried with:

```
directory "/.../dir" do
  recursive true
end
```

Comment: `Dir["/../dir/**/*"]`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to start that path with `/..`. That's one level below root, which doesn't exist. On my linux system it returns root, so the `..` isn't doing anything.